# Set background color of a cell in datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

How to set background color of specific cells in datagrid. I tried it through item renderer. But the problem with item renderer is that until the data is not populated in datagrid background color does not work. I want the cell or set of cells to be highlighted even if there is no data in datagrid.

Please find my code below:

MAin.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="onComplete()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.formats.BackgroundColor;

            import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;
            private var dataArr:Array=new Array({data1:"Value"},{data1:"Value"},{data1:"Value"},{data1:"Value"},{data1:"Value"},{data1:"Value"})
            private function onComplete():void{
                var colsArr:Array=new Array();
                var column1:AdvancedDataGridColumn=new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
                column1.headerText="Header1";
                //column1.setStyle("backgroundColor","0xcccccc");
                column1.dataField="data1";
                colsArr.push(column1);
                var column2:AdvancedDataGridColumn=new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
                column2.headerText="Header2";
                //column2.setStyle("backgroundColor","0xcccccc");
                column2.dataField="data2";
                colsArr.push(column2);
                var column3:AdvancedDataGridColumn=new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
                column3.headerText="Header3";
                //column3.setStyle("backgroundColor","0xcccccc");
                column3.dataField="data3";
                colsArr.push(column3);
                var column4:AdvancedDataGridColumn=new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
                column4.headerText="Header4";
                //column4.setStyle("backgroundColor","0xcccccc");
                column4.dataField="data4";
                colsArr.push(column4);
                var column5:AdvancedDataGridColumn=new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
                column5.headerText="Header5";
                column5.dataField="data5";
                colsArr.push(column5);
                var column6:AdvancedDataGridColumn=new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
                column6.headerText="Header6";
                column6.dataField="data6";
                colsArr.push(column6);
                var column7:AdvancedDataGridColumn=new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
                column7.headerText="Header7";
                column7.dataField="data7";
                colsArr.push(column7);
                sampleDG.columns=colsArr;
                sampleDG.rowCount=colsArr.length;
            }
            private function myStyleFunction(data:Object, col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Object{
                if(col.headerText=="Header1" || col.headerText=="Header2" || col.headerText=="Header3"){
                    return {backgroundColor:0xcccccc, color:0xff0000};
                }else{
                    return {backgroundColor:0xffffff, color:0xff0000};
                }
                return {};
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="sampleDG" rowCount="3" width="350" horizontalScrollPolicy="on" height="300"
                         cachePolicy="on"  styleFunction="myStyleFunction" itemRenderer="com.ADGItemRenderer"/>
</s:Application>
```

ADGItemRenderer:

```
package com.ssc.pna.secmaster.renderer
{
    import com.ssc.pna.components.MktDGColumn;

    import mx.charts.styles.HaloDefaults;
    import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer;
    import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridListData;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;
    import mx.styles.CSSStyleDeclaration;
    import mx.styles.IStyleManager2;
    import mx.styles.StyleManager;

    [Style(name="rowColor", type="uint", format="Color", inherit="yes")] 

    public class ADGItemRenderer extends AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer
    {

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        public var dataType:Object; 
        public var precision:Object;
        private static var stylesInited:Boolean = initStyles();

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        private static function initStyles():Boolean
        {
            return true;
        }

        public function ADGItemRenderer()
        {
            super();
            background = true;
            backgroundColor=0xFFFFCC;
        }

        override public function validateNow():void
        {
            //listData=listData;
             var _listDataDummy:BaseListData=listData;


            backgroundColor = 0xFFFFCC;

            super.validateNow();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to change the background color of all the cells in the first three columns even when there is no data(as i tried it doing in the code above).
Initially i tried to set the color at column level by using SetStyle but faced some issue. so thought to change the approach. Link below will give you the details about that issue:

[background color disappears when scrolling horizontally in advance datagrid in flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847099/background-color-disappears-when-scrolling-horizontally-in-advance-datagrid-in-f)

Comment: The correct answer is to use an itemRenderer.  Please edit your question and share your code for the itemRenderer; and then we'll be better suited to help you.

Comment: Please find the code attached in the question!!